# Convert a byte list to python list

Tags: python

here is my task description, as I need to pass some data to the GCP cloud task HTTP request body, I need to convert a list to bytes list(as it is only accept bye data type), then convert back into a python list for the GCP cloud function. Right now I am having trouble converting a byte list back to a python list. Here is my code. I use the join method to join all the characters but it is still displayed separately.

```
dataset_id='ICN444499559951515151'

name='testing_1'

payload=[dataset_id,name]

byte_list=str(payload).encode()

x=byte_list.decode("utf-8")

y=reduce(concat,x)

print(list(x.join()))
```

but it still cannot join as a list as I wish. I want the result to be like this `["ICN444499559951515151","testing1"]` and able to extract data for the cloud function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `byte_list` isn't actually a list. It is a byte string representing a list. Similarly, `x` is a string, not a list.

To convert the string back to a list, you have to apply some logic on how this should happens, as there is no standard conversion from string to list.

This can be done in one line with a list comprehension:

```
[e.strip().replace("'","") for e in x.strip("[]").split(",")]
# ['ICN444499559951515151', 'testing_1']
```

The above code takes `x` removes the surrounding brackets (`strip("[]")` and splits the string at ´,´ (`split(",")`. This results in a list of strings, but still with some disturbing single quotes and spaces. Therefore, for each of those elements `e`, the code removes surrounding empty spaces (`strip()`) and replaces single quotes with empty strings (`replace("'","")`.

Comment: This is hacky and may not work, consider this list:
dataset_id='ICN444499559951515151'  
name="Jame's data"  
The output is ['ICN444499559951515151', '"James data"'],  
and not ['ICN444499559951515151', "Jame's data"]  
I think snakecharmerb's answer is better for this task.

Answer (score 4):

`str(payload)` converts the list to a str, and this is not an easily  reversible operation.

A better approach is to use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to serialise and deserialise the list and its elements.

```
>>> import json
>>> dataset_id='ICN444499559951515151'
>>> name='testing_1'
>>> payload=[dataset_id,name]
>>> serialised = json.dumps(payload)
>>> serialised
'["ICN444499559951515151", "testing_1"]'
>>> byte_list = serialised.encode()
>>> y = byte_list.decode("utf-8")
>>> x = json.loads(y)
>>> x
['ICN444499559951515151', 'testing_1']
>>>
```

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a widely used standard for serialising and deserialising data sent over http (and other protocols).

Comment: Under the given context, your approach should be the right way to go.